# fabric-ca-client enroll with error Error: POST failure of request: POST http://localhost:7054/enroll

Tags: hyperledger-fabric-ca

When I started fabricCA server with docker, Using the command

```
fabric-ca-client enroll -u http://admin:adminpw@localhost:7054
```

an error occurs

> Error: POST failure of request: POST http://localhost:7054/enroll
> {"hosts":["ubuntu"],"certificate_request":"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----\nMIIBPDCB4wIBADBdMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEXMBUGA1UECBMOTm9ydGggQ2Fyb2xp\nbmExFDASBgNVBAoTC0h5cGVybGVkZ2VyMQ8wDQYDVQQLEwZGYWJyaWMxDjAMBgNV\nBAMTBWFkbWluMFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEA0xOrwYS5y3LYsWo\n4SVsajuCAV3fYhxF3p1HbW4koQyjH1oHjCp3+dXfBbp2tV5ADdHrAemnrC+JR9zq\nvq1tKqAkMCIGCSqGSIb3DQEJDjEVMBMwEQYDVR0RBAowCIIGdWJ1bnR1MAoGCCqG\nSM49BAMCA0gAMEUCIQC7DFmf8FQ4CEZfI9x+rIlymeVbfz7kdcN1w3O9i9YrbwIg\nJeBScp3ut4sSqRdgSYuM+TjDO+eDMiFvbvGEUJYe7Ic=\n-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----\n","profile":"","crl_override":"","label":"","NotBefore":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z","NotAfter":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z","ReturnPrecert":false,"CAName":""}: Post "http://localhost:7054/enroll": net/http: HTTP/1.x transport connection broken: malformed HTTP response "\x15\x03\x01\x00\x02\x02\x16"

docker-compose.yml:

```
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca
    container_name: ca.buyer.com
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca.buyer.com
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.buyer.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/78e27e6db18578fefd8a98fe74f8393e4cb5ee414e887f3325e4105239757727_sk
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.buyer.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/78e27e6db18578fefd8a98fe74f8393e4cb5ee414e887f3325e4105239757727_sk
    ports:
      - 7054:7054
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw -d'
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/buyer.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - ca.buyer.com
```

Comment: Could you show your `docker-compose-ca.yaml` file? My guess is that the port you have in there for `ca-buyer` is different from the 7054 you are using here. At least that was the culprit of this exact same error on my end.

Answer (score 0):

Fabric CA server is started with TLS enabled. The client should pass the tls cert during the enroll process.

Please try

fabric-ca-client enroll -u http://admin:adminpw@localhost:7054 --tls.certfiles $FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_CERTFILE

Comment: I have tried this but still facing the issue

Answer (score 0):

The error is because the port is not open.
When on a cloud platform this error can be solved by going to the firewall section in the cloud VM and creating a new firewall rule with the port . Refer Youtube for this on how to open ports in cloud platform.

Answer (score 0):

yes, so I think the reason is cryptogen generate.Maybe If I use fabric-ca generate will be ok

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).